# ml64 weird error output

Tags: windows, masm

Hello Stack Overflowers!
I have wrote a asm code file that i'm trying to build using ml64 (v14.00.23506.0)
but the assembler gives me weird output.. like there something wrong in line 1..
i'm sure there is nothing wrong with the code because it worked well on other ml64 version. it worked well with the ml64 from VS Community 2015, the current ml64 from VC++ BuildTools Tech-Preview gives me the error in the screenshot.
i tried ml64 from VS Express 2015 and VC BuildTools 2015 TP, both give same error.
ps. im building with a batch script that i wrote and coding in VIM.

can anyone guide me on how to overcome this issue?

-- UPDATED --
that's the cmd build error after i fixed the previous batch errors.
still weird error, can anyone understand?
(thats a test code)

[image: the output window]
[image: cmd output window]

```
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib    
EXTERN GetModuleHandleExW:PROC
EXTERN MessageBoxW:PROC
EXTERN ExitProcess:PROC

.DATA
ALIGN 4
    pwszMessage WORD "H","e","l","l","o",","," ","W","o","r","l","d","!"
    WORD 0
    pwszCaption WORD "M","e","s","s","a","g","e","B","o","x"
    WORD 0
    hInstance QWORD 0
.CODE
entry PROC
    sub rsp, 28h
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rdx, rcx
    lea r8, [hInstance]
    call    GetModuleHandleExW
    lea rdx, [pwszMessage]
    lea r8, [pwszCaption]
    mov r9d, 40h
    call    MessageBoxW
    call    ExitProcess ; rcx suppose to hold 0 already
    add rsp, 28h
ret
entry ENDP
END
```

Comment: the issue is that the errors from my batch script and ml64.exe messages got mixed somehow that I couldn't tell which error belong to what. but i managed to figure it out.. so now I'm working on fixing all errors. if i had something to Hex-view i would. its just nothing got built because of the errors

Comment: the batch errors are fixed  but ml64 still acts weird.. the error messages are not clear, even if i build directly through cmd without the batch script

Comment: Can you show us your batch script?

Comment: i figured it out, the problem was in the system environment variables, ml64 worked only from a specific folder, so i checked if the "faulty" ml64 executables will work from the specific folder that the previous working ml64 was, and they worked just fine! its just that ml64 couldnt direct me to this issue it instead wrote we weird errors as shown in the screenshots. the batch script is no longer relevant so forgive me for not posting it content.